# MS SQL 2008 - Transactional Publication failure - The process could not execute 'sp_replcmds' on 'SERVERNAME'

Tags: sql-server

I got MS SQL 2008 running on Windows Server 2008 R2.

Everything is fresh install running on a VM.

I can make a Snapshot Publication without problems. But I am unable to make a Transactional Publication, I get errors even before I try to configure a subscriber. Here's how I did things:

1. I configure Distribution. (DEFAULT SETTINGS)
2. I start the New Publication Wizard.

   - Transactional publication
   - I select "Creat a snapshot immediately"
   - I configure the security settings for the Snapshot Agent and Log Reader Agent (Using the Windows account Domain Admin)
   - The Publication is created succesfully, no errors.
   - The "View Snapshot Agent Status" report no errors - 100% success.
   - Going to the Replication Monitor, that's where the errors begin - Error with the Log Reader Agent - "The process could not execute 'sp_replcmds' on 'SERVERNAME'..." [see picture]

What am I doing wrong? Or what am I missing?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From BOL:

> Only members of the sysadmin fixed server role or the db_owner fixed database role can execute sp_replcmds.

So, who is the logreader agent running as?  That is, how is it connecting to your publisher database?  If that user doesn't have db_owner or is a sysadmin, you'll get a failure.

Comment: Like I said in the original post: I configure the security settings for the Snapshot Agent and Log Reader Agent (Using the Windows account Domain Admin) - If that doesn't answer the question, can you tell me how to check who is the logreader agent running as?

Comment: I took that to mean "as a domain admin, I configured the security".  One other thing to check is who the dbo user maps to in your database.  Since I see in one of your other replies that this is a restore from somewhere else, it's possible that it doesn't map to a valid login.  If that's the case, fix that and see if your problem persists.

Comment: No idea how.. mind holding my hand? :p But seriously I'm a SQL noob, no idea how to check who the dbo user maps to in the database :(

Comment: Is that what you're looking for? http://img543.imageshack.us/img543/1971/85318219.jpg

Comment: OK i'm definitely getting somewhere, I tried again with a different database and it worked! And I compared the dbo properties between the 2 databases, and I noticed that the database with the problem is missing a "Login name" (as seen blank in the screenshot above) so now I just need to figure out how to fill that grayed out field

Comment: OK found it. From the DB propreties > Files > Owner. Thanks guys. Problem solved.

Comment: Alternatively, you can do "alter user [dbo] with login = [your login here]"  The dbo user and the db owner can be different, I think.

Answer (score 1):

If the subscriber database has been restored from a backup to a different instance, check if the domain admin user is orphaned.

use [subscriber]
go
exec sp_change_users_login 'report'
go

Comment: The database I'm using is restored from a backup that comes from a SQL 2005, is that the problem?